# Missing required parameter when using injection

Tags: php, laravel, routes, laravel-8

I have this route:

```
Route::resource('riskfields', RiskfieldsController::class)->except('show');
```

Within the `RiskfieldController/edit` I'm calling the edit view as:

```
public function edit(Riskfield $riskField)
{
    return view('riskfields.edit', [
        'riskField' => $riskField
    ]);
}
```

where `Riskfield` is the model.

So, inside `edit.blade.php` I have:

```
{{ Form::open(['route' => ['riskfields.update', $riskField->id], 'method' => 'put', 'autocomplete' => 'off']) }}
```

when I access to this endpoint: `/admin/riskfields/1/edit`

I get:

> Missing required parameter for [Route: riskfields.update] [URI: admin/riskfields/{riskfield}] [Missing parameter: riskfield]. (View: /var/www/html/resources/views/riskfields/edit.blade.php)

The problem's that I have inject the model, so I don't know what's happening there.

This is the update method:

```
public function update(Riskfield $riskField, Request $request): RedirectResponse
```

Someone could help?

UPDATE:

dd ouput:

[image]

Comment: if you dd riskfield object in the controller do youget the expected variable?

Comment: @MátyásGrőger check my update, seems I'm getting the model

Comment: could you check your rendered form with inspector and make a screenshot about that? The actual html form that this code renders. Thanks

Comment: @MátyásGrőger how can I inspect the edit form? If I open the page `/admin/riskfields/1/edit` I get the error above

Comment: ahh right. Well for me personally I have never used the Form syntax. I prefer to write the form myself in the view, there fore I am not sure what it renders. But the porblem is that when you define the route 'route' => ['riskfields.update', $riskField->id], it fails to render the id correctly

Comment: @MátyásGrőger seems that I was able to fix the problem, I have to specify in edit method this syntax: `edit(Riskfield $riskfield)` and not `edit(Riskfield $riskField)`, could you confirm that?

Comment: yes, I am glad you resolved it

Comment: Shouldn't the request object come first in the list of arguments? `public function update(Riskfield $riskField, Request $request)` should be `public function update(Request $request, Riskfield $riskField)`

Answer (score 1):

This problem stopped me for half an hour, but I hope my answer will help someone. Essentially I have to change this:

```
public function edit(Riskfield $riskField)
```

into:

```
public function edit(Riskfield $riskfield)
```

The parameter must have the same name convention defined within the route, so I've executed `php artisan route:list` and it was `admin/riskfields/{riskfield}`

Hope to help someone.

Comment: I don't see a difference there? Am I missing something?

Comment: @waterloomatt I had initially defined the parameter as `riskField` using the camel case (it's my habit to use this convention), but in laravel you must define the paramether in the same way it was defined in the router, so in this case `$riskfield`

Comment: Ah, I missed the capitalization. Thanks.